# Scheduling php task on shared server

Tags: php, scheduled-tasks

I am looking to schedule a task which would be executed at date/time provided by end user.
The date/time would be selected through date picker and stored in database using php file.
This php file could also do whatever is required to schedule the job. The file to be executed is also residing on the same server.
I have looked at iron.io but they require that all code resides on their servers which is not very good idea in my case since I have to access the database and it would change my setup a lot. 
I have also read that cron running periodically can be used to do so but I wonder if there is any service out there which would not require running cron every minute. It would just trigger execution of my script and hopefully could pass one variable to it.

Comment: There are many share hosting that no allow the user make cronjobs, so first you have to ask if you have permision

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ATrigger](http://atrigger.com/) scheduling service.
PHP library is available to create scheduled tasks without overhead. 
Also some useful features are available such as error log, analytics, tasks listing. All codes on your server, just set a URL for your task.

For example, this will call your task after 10 minutes:

```
//Create
ATrigger::doCreate("10minute", "http://www.example.com/myTask?something", $tags);
```

You can use this kind of services in **shared hosting**.

**Disclaimer**: I was among the ATrigger team. It's a freeware and I have not any commercial purpose.

Comment: This thing is more than useful! Thanks!